# Spooling non-ascii characters to printer

Tags: printing, non-ascii-characters

I have a program that basically creates a text report containing non-ASCII characters (Traditional Chinese, to be exact). The file opens up fine in text editors.

The main problem I'm having is printing this text report

1. If I print this file from notepad, the form feeds/page breaks
   aren't recognized and the alignment goes haywire. Non-ASCII characters show fine.
2. If I use the command "type filename > \\machine\printer", the alignment works     but all non-ASCII characters print as gibberish.

I've tried several variations of raw printing, setting system locale, changing code page, etc but can't get it to work.

Originally, the program was allowed to spool directly to printer (and it worked fine) but due to technology changes, direct spooling is forbidden. I can only work with the text-file as-is after it's been generated.

Does anyone have an idea how to work with this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way -basically using powershell and force the encoding to UTF-8 in Get-Content. Apparently cmd spooling will never be able to handle this...